# Correct usage of Java EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, java-threads

I'm using Java `EntityManager` to work with database as follows:

```
  Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
  properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://"+dbProperties.getHost()+":"+dbProperties.getPort()+"/"+dbProperties.getDbName());
  properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", dbProperties.getUser());
  properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", dbProperties.getPassword());      
  entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestDAL", properties).createEntityManager();
```

And the application is working with several threads and sometimes the application is hanging when many requests come.

The thread dump is as follows:

```
    - threadId:Thread 11208 - state:BLOCKED stackTrace: - java.util.HashSet.add(java.lang.Object) @bci=8, line=217 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise) 
- java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(java.util.Collection) @bci=29, line=342 (Compiled frame) 
    - java.util.LinkedHashSet. (java.util.Collection) @bci=22, line=169 (Interpreted frame) 
    - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.ManagedTypeImpl.getAttributes() @bci=13, line=160 (Interpreted frame) 
    - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.IdentifiableTypeImpl.initializeIdAttributes() @bci=12, line=95 (Compiled frame) 
    - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.initialize(java.lang.ClassLoader) @bci=251, line=493 (Compiled frame) 
    - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.getMetamodel(java.lang.ClassLoader) @bci=25, line=3476 (Interpreted frame) 
    - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.util.Map) @bci=955, line=754 (Interpreted frame) 
    - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession() @bci=54, line=205 (Interpreted frame) 
    - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(java.util.Map, javax.persistence.SynchronizationType) @bci=5, line=305 (Interpreted frame) 
    - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(java.util.Map, javax.persistence.SynchronizationType) @bci=90, line=337 (Interpreted frame) 
    - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager() @bci=3, line=303 (Interpreted frame)
```

What would be the possible root cause?

Comment: Is there an exception that goes with this?

Comment: @bradimus there are no any exception.But around 100 threads are in BLOCKED status.

Comment: @bradimus , I changed the code.

Comment: How do you cleanup you connections/close the entitymanager? Might be a resource leak.

Comment: If you're using a single entityManager from several threads, then you have a serious design problem. An entity anager is not thread-safe. Typically, each transaction should create one and close it when it's done. An EntityManagerFactory, on the other hand, is thread-safe and should be created once and only once.

Comment: @JBNizet , I'm using a new entityManager  for each thread and use entityManager.clear(); to close connections.

Comment: @bradimus, please refer my above comment.

Comment: clear() doesn't close connections. My advice is to have 1 EM per transaction. Not per thread. And to close it when the transaction is done.

Comment: @JBNizet, Ok. I will do it.

Comment: @JBNizet I have used entityManager  per one transaction.But it didn't worked. And do you have any idea, why threads are in blocking status. is it related to creating EntityManager?

Comment: @bradimus, do you have any idea, why threads are in blocking status. is it related to creating EntityManager?

Comment: @JBNizet In the following article it says "It is almost never a good idea to have more than one instance of an EntityManager in use " for RESOURCE_LOCAL. This is the opposite side of what you are suggesting right ?

Comment: Which following article?

Comment: sorry article is ref http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html